# Hide image in PHP

Tags: php, image

I have this page that is showing an image place holder even using the following PHP.  It seems like the image should palceholder should not be displayed using <>"0"

http://westerndesignconference.com/intheloop/

```
<?php if ($row_rsGallery['artistPhoto']<>"0"){ ?>
<img src="../img/artists/<?php echo $row_rsGallery['artistPhoto']; ?>" width="100%" />
<?php } 
?>
<?php if ($row_rsGallery['artistPhoto2']<>"0"){ ?>
<img src="../img/artists/<?php echo $row_rsGallery['artistPhoto2']; ?>" width="100%" />
<?php } 
?>
```

Comment: is it possible you confuse `"0"` with `null`...?

Comment: change `<>"0"` to `<>""` or `if(!empty($row_rsGallery['artistPhoto'])){`

Answer (score 0):

`var_dump('mystring' <> "0");`

`var_dump(null <> "0");`

`var_dump("" <> "0");`

Will evaluate to true.

Additionally `var_dump('mystring' == 0);` will also evaluate to true.

What you want is

```
if(false === empty($row_rsGallery['artistPhoto'])) {
}
```

This will ensure `$row_rsGallery['artistPhoto']` is set without throwing an index not found error, and contains a value other than false, or 0.